# ggplot2: geom_bar with custom y limits

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I want to draw a bar chart with `ggplot2` along with custom y limits.

```
Type <- LETTERS[1:5]
Y    <- c(99, 99.5, 99.0, 98.8, 98.5)

df <- data.frame(Type, Y)
```

The following code works fine for bar chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Type, y = Y, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw()
```

However, I'm not able to set the y limits. See the code below.

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Type, y = Y, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(90, 100)) + 
  theme_bw()

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Type, y = Y, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ylim(90, 100) + 
  theme_bw()
```

**Edited**

I guess this behavior is due to `stat = "identity"`.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible as `geom_bar` goes from `0` to `y` (its like inserting break in y axis). Why not to plot `geom_point`?

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas for your comment. Yes, `geom_point` could be another possibility. However, I want to show these points throw bars. Any thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution using `geom_rect()` instead of `geom_bar()`:

```
# Generate data
Type <- LETTERS[1:5]
Y    <- c(99, 99.5, 99.0, 98.8, 98.5)
df   <- data.frame(Type, Y)

# Plot data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
    geom_rect(data = df, 
              aes(xmin = as.numeric(Type) - 0.3, 
                  xmax = as.numeric(Type) + 0.3, 
                  ymin = 90, ymax = Y,
                  fill = Type)) +
    scale_x_continuous(label = df$Type, breaks = 1:nrow(df))
```

In `geom_rect()` specify x coordinates as `as.numeric(X) -/+ value`; `ymin` coordinates as wanted lower limit and `ymax` as actual Y values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PoGibas for useful answer.  Would highly appreciate if you help me to remove the blank space below the rectangles so that y should start from 90. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 you mean space between rectangles and ticks?

Comment: yes the extra space between rectangles and x ticks.

Answer (score 10):

Alternative, using `coord_cartesian`:

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Type, y = Y, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(90, 100)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

Gives you:

[image]

Comment: This solution is more appealing. Thanks @Luke C for your nice answer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for with `coord_cartesian(ylim = range(df$Y))`.

Comment: @MYaseen208 - Good call, that's pretty slick.